# How to set "Admin Notify" preference based on form input value?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have a {exp:freeform:form} in my template and would like to set the admin_notify paramter based on value selected from a radio button or drop down.

Is this possible? I am building a simple form that needs to be send to the relevent person so the admin email address depends on the option selected..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [freeform recipients](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_recipients) tag pair, which allows the user to select from a list of possible delivery options.

Comment: Seconded. That is the tool you need.