# Choosing user_notification_template based on selection made in form

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Is there a way to specify a user_notification_template based on a select made in the form?

I have three options:

```
Red
Green
Blue
```

If the user chooses red then the red notification is sent upon form submit, green for green and blue for blue. Is this at all possible? (Just using colours for simplicity)

I did see [How to set "Admin Notify" preference based on form input value?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/12990/2420) question/answer however I'm not sure how to use this in my case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `user_notification_template=""` is a parameter, and there is no form field for it, it isn't possible to modify this setting once the form has loaded. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

This may be far-fetched, but you could use javascript to reload the form with a new user_notification_template value after selecting one of your options. The value if the user_notification_template would be passed in a segment in the URL.

For example, if you select "Red", the form reloads with a URL link this (this is an *example*): `http://mysite.com/contact/redTemplate`

Then, in your `{exp:freeform:form}` (or `{exp:freeform:composer}`) parameters, use the segment in your `user_notification_template=""` parameter, i.e.:

```
user_notification_template="{segment_3}"
```

Of course make sure to have a `redTemplate` notification template set up in the CP.

> *Be careful of parse order! **Turn on Template Debugging** if necessary*